# face detection with AVfoundation swift 2

Tags: ios, camera, swift2, avfoundation, face-detection

So i have successfully set up a little project that uses AV foundation to start the back or front camera with the push of a button. Now that i have control of the camera I wanted to implement the face detection to a level where I can map out, on the preview of the camera, where that face is.

The tutorials i have seen online have used the `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` and the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` and the main [tutorial](https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/camera-capture-on-ios/) i am trying to follow uses a GLkit to take control of the live stream. I can't follow it because their site's code doesn't match their github and i have too many questions and lose ends.

Can anyone help me set up face detection to a level where i can map it on the screen with AVfoundation base? or point me to a good place to learn to accomplish this?

Comment: So,upto now, have you set up or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Great, you already know about the Capture Session stuff, now you need to do is use `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`.

Implement its `func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, 
   didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, 
                       from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)` method.

You code may looks like this:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    var faces = [CGRect]()

    for metadataObject in metadataObjects as! [AVMetadataObject] {
        if metadataObject.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeFace {
                let transformedMetadataObject = previewLayer.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObject)
                let face = transformedMetadataObject.bounds
                faces.append(face)
        }
    }

    print("FACE",faces)
    }
```

Once you found the faces, you may use other layer to draw rectangles around faces or do other things.

Here's a [demo](https://github.com/KrisYu/stackoverflow/tree/master/faceDetectionDemo2) you can refer to.